# Selenium/Chromedriver: Can't find element in iframe

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium/Chromedriver via Protractor. I'm switching to an iframe, waiting for the contents to load, and then planning to manipulate elements inside it. But it's never recognizing that the contents have loaded.

```
browser.driver.switchTo().frame("myView");

browser.driver.wait(function() {
    return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.id("myDiv"))
        .then(function (isPresent) {
            return isPresent;
        });
}, 20000, "Taking too long to load!");
```

myDiv is definitely present within 20 seconds, but wait() times out.

I've tried switching to using browser.driver.findElement(), but got the same result.

I've made sure I'm updated to Chromedriver 2.21 (which fixed an earlier error).

Any ideas what else I could be doing wrong?

**ETA per comment:** This is all I'm getting for an error log...

```
   Message:
     Error: Taking too long to load!
 Wait timed out after 20069ms
   Stacktrace:
     Error: Taking too long to load!
Wait timed out after 20069ms
==== async task ====
Taking too long to load!
    at /Users/me/Documents/My-Test/specs/myWorkflow.js:82:20
==== async task ====
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/me/Documents/My-Test/specs/myWorkflow.js:79:14)
==== async task ====
Asynchronous test function: it()
Error
    at [object Object].<anonymous> (/Users/me/Documents/My-Test/specs/myWorkflow.js:7:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/Documents/My-Test/specs/myWorkflow.js:5:1)
```

Comment: Can you provide traceback log also?

Comment: I'm not getting much of one, but sure.

Comment: Can it find the `by.id("myDiv")`?

Comment: @Buaban: No, it can't, that's the whole problem.

Comment: I've found a workaround: calling browser.driver.sleep(2000).then() and then switching to the iframe and looking for myDiv inside the then() function. It technically satisfies the needs of my test, in that it fails if myDiv hasn't shown up within 20 seconds, but I hate wasting time if it shows up sooner. I don't consider this a real answer.

Comment: Can you also provide brief HTML of the frame? Is `myView` name or id?

Comment: @nilesh: It's definitely the id.

Comment: Can you provide frame html? There doesn't seem anything wrong in what you are doing

Comment: If sleeping before switching to the frame works, then you might need something to `browser.wait` until the frame is present (which would avoid the hard-coded `sleep(2000)`), THEN switch to the frame, THEN check for the presence of the element.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten around similar issues by adding a sleep statement, instead of using a wait loop. In c# I would use thread.sleep(20000); for a 20 second wait. Most of mine are in the 1 to 5 second range.

To clarify: I'm suggesting removing the loop that is he is using to check for the element and instead using a simple sleep type command then interacting with the element.

In Selenium using C# I have used the following statement to provide a fixed wait time while an element loads before clicking the element. This element happens to be a link, but it can be any element

```
      //sleep time so UX can load
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

      //open the new  form
        By newButton = By.XPath("/dummy/xpath");
        IWebElement button = driver.FindElement(newButton);
        button.Click();
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer? if so, how it solves the question?

Comment: Seconding @LeonardoAlvesMachado .   This can be saved if you apply what you're suggesting to the code provided in the question,  but otherwise it should be a comment.